# Confusion about order of accuracy of Simpson's rule

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ which is to be integrated in the interval $[a,b]$ using step size $h$. Also, $b = a+2n\cdot h$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I am unable to understand how exactly does the ordinary [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) have an order of accuracy 3 in some cases, while 4 in others (it says, when the points are distributed symmetrically in the interval). I tried looking it up online but either there's no explicit proof, or they don't mention it at all. Is there any book / resource that explains this well?

Comment: Naively, you would expect that a quadratic interpolant would have a pointwise error scaling as $(b-a)^3$ and therefore an integral error scaling as $(b-a)^4$ (you get another factor of the length when you integrate). This is indeed what happens when you use a non-symmetric method based on quadratic interpolation. Simpson in particular gains an additional order because of the symmetry.

Comment: Basically, the fourth order term from $[a,c]$ and the fourth order term from $[c,b]$ cancel one another, where $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$. This is analogous to how centered difference schemes for numerical differentiation get an additional order "for free".

Comment: Another sometimes confusing thing about this discussion is that a composite integration method "loses an order" relative to the single interval version of the method. That's because you have to add up $N=C/h$ terms which are each proportional to $h^k$, so the sum is proportional to $h^{k-1}$.

Comment: A nice trick you can use to anticipate this is to check that the Simpson rule exactly integrates cubic functions. By shifting and linearity you can see that this only requires the simple calculation: $\int_{-1}^1 x^3 dx = 0 = \frac{1}{3} \left ( (-1)^3 + 4 \cdot 0 + 1 \right )$. Thus you might expect that the Simpson error estimate doesn't involve the third derivative, and indeed it does not.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Ian!
Could you recommend any book where this is explained in detail? I would like to reference this, and show the proof if possible.

Comment: My undergrad text was Numerical Analysis by Timothy Sauer. I think it covered quadrature (although we didn't do it in our unit).